# Accessing function/method through cURL

Tags: php, curl

If I used `SoapClient`, my code would look something like this:

```
$baseurl = 'http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($baseurl);
print_r($client->GetGeoIP(array('IPAddress'=>'123.45.67.890')));
```

So using `$client`, I can access the `GetGeoIP` method. How would do the same thing using cURL?

So far I've set up the code as:

```
$curl = curl_init($baseurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rawPOSTdata = array(
    "IPAddress"     =>  "123.45.67.890",    
    );
// now how do I specify that I want to send $rawPOSTdata to the GetGeoIP() function?
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $rawPOSTdata);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));      

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Now where and how do I specify the function call `GetGeoIP`?

## EDIT

After extending the SOAP class, this is what I got for `$request`

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.webservicex.net/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:GetGeoIP>
         <ns1:IPAddress>123.45.67.890</ns1:IPAddress>
      </ns1:GetGeoIP>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So if I got this right, I should store this inside a variable and use in the

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_string)` ?

Comment: Check out [SoapClientTimeout](http://www.darqbyte.com/2009/10/21/timing-out-php-soap-calls/) that was built on top of cURL (to allow timeouts).

Comment: I'm not sure how that applies to my query. Also, there is curl request example shown there, but again it doesn't show how to specify the method call

Comment: You can see it setting `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);`, so you should be able to just do a `var_dump($request)` to see how it handles it.

Comment: @h2ooooooo In order to use `$obj->__doRequest(...` what should `$request` be? The documentation says `The XML SOAP request`. I'm not sure I understand what that means

Comment: Like I mentioned, set up the class, then simply print out the `$request` var after you call `GetGeoIP` and check.

Comment: Hmm..but that is what I'm looking for - Figuring out how to call `GetGeoIP` trough curl

Comment: Okay, like I mentioned: Use the class that I linked. After you pasted this into your project, create a new `SoapClientTimeout` instance just like you would with a regular `SoapClient` instance (all you have to do is rename `SoapClient` in your original code to `SoapClientTimeout`). Now, go into the `SoapClientTimeout` class and create a new line in the top of the `__doRequest` method: `var_dump($request)`. The result of this dump will be your answer.

Comment: Ah..silly me..anyways, did that and it returned `string(282) "
123.45.67.890
"` Anyways thanks for your time..I'll figure it out somehow

Comment: It only outputs that because you aren't seeing the XML characters (as you're printing in HTML - hence the length of 282). `Right click -> View source` OR use `header('Content-type: text/plain')` OR `echo htmlentities($request);`.

Comment: Nice. Updating my question to avoid clutter.

Comment: @h2ooooooo If you can post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it

Comment: I think you should post it as an answer yourself (I'm pretty sure you can even with 1 rep), and I'll gladly upvote it. Solving your own problems is very legit and very useful for other people Googling their way to figure this out. Good job! And yes - you're right - simply use it as `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I can post it myself. Just wanted to reward you for your time. 25 rep won't feel like much to you, but that's the least I could do as a token of appreciation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download and use [SoapClientTimeout](http://www.darqbyte.com/2009/10/21/timing-out-php-soap-calls/), and then simply change the class's `__doRequest` emthod and include a dump of the `$request` variable to figure out how `SoapClient` wraps it:

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = FALSE) {
    echo htmlentities($request);
    //...
}
```

and call it as a regular soap client:

```
$baseurl = 'http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClientTimeout($baseurl);
print_r($client->GetGeoIP(array('IPAddress'=>'123.45.67.890')));
```

..you'll get your answer:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.webservicex.net/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:GetGeoIP>
         <ns1:IPAddress>123.45.67.890</ns1:IPAddress>
      </ns1:GetGeoIP>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This entire XML string goes into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: Dammit! Upvote requires 15 rep...anyways thanks again

Comment: @EnthusiacticProgrammer No worries - I'm just glad I could help, and you did the exact right thing which is to be helpful and figuring stuff out yourself. Sometimes it might be annoying to use a couple of hours on something another person could figure out in an instant, but you'll be able to use the logic of debugging in pretty much every single programming language/project you'll ever encounter.

Comment: Couldn't have worded it better. Cheers!